# Does the supremum of the singular value of a matrix H(s), over the RHP, always occur on the imaginary axis?

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum, singular-values

Consider the dynamic system
$$ \dot{x}=Ax+Bu \\ y=Cx+Du $$
where $ A, B, C, D$ are all real constant matrices. $A$ is square while others may not. Also, assume $A$ is stable (all eigenvalues have negative real parts). The transfer matrix (from $u$ to $y$) in the Laplace domain is given by
$$ H(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1}B+D$$
The $\bf{H}_\infty$ norm of the transfer matrix is defined by
$$\left\lVert H\right\rVert_\infty\triangleq\sup_{\text{Re}(s)>0}{\sigma_{\text{max}} (H(s))}$$
where $\sigma_{\text{max}}(H(s))$ denotes the maximum singular value of the matrix $H(s)$.

My question is: Why does the $\bf{H}_{\infty}$ norm of $H$ always occur on the imaginary axis, i.e.,
$$ \left\lVert H\right\rVert_\infty\triangleq\sup_{\text{Re}(s)>0}{\sigma_{\text{max}} (H(s))} = \sup_{\omega\in \mathbb{R}}{\sigma_{\text{max}} (H(j\omega))}$$

(as stated in [here](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/bisection_hinfty.pdf))? Is it a general rule for any arbitrary matrix as a function of $s$, or is special to the transfer matrix of a stable state-space system?

If the $\bf{H}_\infty$ norm is an analytic function in $s$ over the RHP, then by the maximum modulus principle plus the fact that $||H(s)||\rightarrow0$ as $\text{Re}(s)\rightarrow \infty$ in our system, we can argue that the supremum will certainly occur on the imaginary axis. However, as far as I know, the maximum singular value may not be a smooth function, not to say analytic (?). Appreciate any comment.